# how to replace "randomize" button with randomise on reload?

Tags: jquery

There is this superb script which I hope to adapt to my hobbies address list, but it has a "Randomize" button, and I would like to replace this "Randomize" button with **"randomize on reload"** script

```
 $(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("div.band").randomize("div.member");
  });
});

(function($) {

$.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {
 return this.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var elems = $this.children(childElem);

  elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });  

  $this.remove(childElem);  

  for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
    $this.append(elems[i]);      

  });    
}
})(jQuery);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want it to randomize when the page loads, can't you just call `$("div.band").randomize("div.member");` outside of the click handler?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.band").randomize("div.member");
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much